# sort date into descending order

Tags: c#, sql, winforms

I want to display the date  into descending  order in Gridview as default.

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
SqlDataAdapter adp = 
   new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Customer.CustomerID, Customer.lastname, Customer.firstname, 
                              Ticket.Date, Ticket.Store, Ticket.Amount, Ticket.NoStub " +
                      "FROM Customer INNER JOIN Ticket ON Customer.CustomerID = Ticket.CustomerID 
                       WHERE Customer.CustomerID like " + txtCustomerID.Text, cn);
adp.Fill(dt);
gvHistory.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 2):

Just add:

```
 order by Ticket.Date desc
```

to the end of your sql statement, like the following:

```
DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT Customer.CustomerID,             Customer.lastname, Customer.firstname, Ticket.Date, Ticket.Store, Ticket.Amount, Ticket.NoStub " +
                                                "FROM Customer INNER JOIN Ticket ON Customer.CustomerID = Ticket.CustomerID WHERE Customer.CustomerID like " + txtCustomerID.Text + " order by Ticket.Date desc", cn);
        adp.Fill(dt);
        gvHistory.DataSource = dt;
```

Answer (score 1):

As @Adels answer you can order by changing your sql statement, if you want to do it by code. try `DataGridView.Sort` method as below

```
gvHistory.Sort(gvHistory.Columns["ColumnName"], ListSortDirection.Descending);
```

Answer (score 1):

1. I suggest using the Sort function on the data grid, as Damith recommended
2. **DO NOT PUT USER PARAMETERS DIRECTLY INTO THE SQL STATEMENT**.  You must use `WHERE Customer.CustomerID like @customerId` and then add a parameter to the command, with `name = @customerId and value = txtCustomerID.Text`.  This 1) prevents user input from destroying the database, 2) prevents bloating the SQL plan cache.

Answer (score 0):

```
System.Data.DataTable dt = new System.Data.DataTable();
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter adp = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter(
                      "SELECT Customer.CustomerID,
                              Customer.lastname, 
                              Customer.firstname, 
                              Ticket.Date, 
                              Ticket.Store, 
                              Ticket.Amount,
                              Ticket.NoStub " +
                      "FROM Customer INNER JOIN Ticket ON 
                              Customer.CustomerID = Ticket.CustomerID WHERE         
                              Customer.CustomerID like " + txtCustomerID.Text + " 
                              order by Ticket.Date desc", cn);
adp.Fill(dt);
gvHistory.DataSource = dt;
```